# How get IntelliSense hints for 3rd party classes as you type in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, intellisense, visual-studio-2019

Currently, I get no IntelliSense hints for classes that are in 3rd party packages that I have not yet imported with `using`.

For example, if i type `ConnectionMul` I get no hints, so I have to instead type the entire classname (`ConnectionMultiplexer`) and then type `Alt+Enter` and only then does it suggest `using StackExhange.Redis`.

I'm used to IntelliJ's hinting with Java. When I have dependencies added to the project, I can just type `Con` and it will already have suggestions including the 3rd party classes. Is there a way to do this in Visual Studio?

Comment: Resharper can do this.

Answer (score 0):

If you've already referenced the type in your project (via assembly or NuGet package), it should show up as a lightbulb action when you've typed a partial match:

[image: Show suggestion to complete type name through lightbulb action]

However, it seems that this requires at least 5 charactes typed - when I try it with `JObj` I don't get the suggestion, but with `JObje` I do.

There are also (for completeness) options under the C# language that suggest using statements from NuGet or the local reference assemblies path once you've typed out the type name:

[image: Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> C# -> Advanced, showing the 'Suggest usings for types in NuGet packages' checkbox]

When this is turned on and you use a type not referenced in your project, you'll see a suggestion like this:

[image: Showing the lightbulb action to install a package from NuGet]

Comment: This didn't work for me. I type `Conne` and it only suggests `{} Zone using System.Security.Policy`. I type `ConnectionMu` and it suggests nothing. Only when I type the complete `ConnectionMultiplexer` does it suggest it.